# Why does Simplify with TimeConstraint return Removed[$$Failure]?

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

I have a rather ugly *Mathematica* expression (edit: shown below) that I would like to simplify with a time constraint; simplifying without a time constraint or memory constraint does not return as long as I've had the patience to wait (a couple of hours).

The problem, which I have not seen before, is that when I execute

```
Simplify[ expression, TimeConstraint -> 3]
```

I get an output that contains things like

> ```
> ...10000 E^(29599743/514000) Removed[$$Failure]...
> ```

The only warning message I receive during execution is

> ```
> Simplify::time: Time spent on a transformation exceeded 3.` seconds, 
> and the transformation was aborted. Increasing the value of TimeConstraint option may   
> improve the result of simplification
> ```

Is this a known issue? I can't find anything about it. I expect when using `TimeConstraint` that I will not get the simplest answer back, but I also expect to get a usable answer (which this is not).

If you think it would be helpful to see the expression I'm trying to simplify, I can post it here. The simplest example in which I've had this problem has a `LeafCount` of `651` and `ByteCount` of `17312`.

**EDIT**

On the suggestion of @JacobAkkerboom, I am adding some more information so someone can try to reproduce the effect. Here is a compressed version of `expression`.

> ```
> expression=Uncompress["1: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"];
> ```

As mentioned, I get the problem simply by running

```
Simplify[ expression, TimeConstraint -> 3 ]
```

(or any other value of `TimeConstraint` I've bothered to check)

`expression` contains standard arithmetic operations, the constants `E` and `Pi`, the operations `Cosh` and `Sinh`, and three variables named `y`, `z`, and `OD` (and yes, I should make `OD` lower case, but it's hard for me to see optical depth as anything but capitals).

**FURTHER EDIT**

I have now reproduced the problem in an expression without a time constraint. The new `expression1` has a `LeafCount` of `186`, so it's not really that complicated.

> ```
> expression1=Uncompress["1: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"];
> Simplify[ expression1 ]
> ```

This returns nearly instantly with three instances of `Removed[$$Failure]`. Since there is no `TimeConstraint` set here, I have no idea what the problem is.  I submitted a help request to *Mathematica*, and I'll let you know if they give any useful response.  In the meantime, thoughts are most welcome. Especially if you can tell me if the problem exists (or not) in other versions of *Mathematica*. I am running 9.0.1 on Mac OS 10.8.3. Thank you to Mr. Wizard for verifying the problem exists in MMA 7 on Windows.

Comment: What version are you using?  What functions is your expression composed of?  For example, could you include the output of `Union @ Cases[expression, _Symbol, {-1}, Heads -> True]` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am using 9.0.1.0.  The output of your suggestion is `{Cosh, E, OD, \[Pi], Plus, Power, Sinh, Times, y, z}`

Comment: What is `OD`?  Also, what do you get from `MemberQ[Names[], "$$Failure"]` before running the `Simplify` line the first time (fresh session)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OD is just another variable, like y or z.  I know capital letters aren't standard Mathematica style, but old habits...
`MemberQ[Names[],"$$Failure"]` gives `False`

Comment: Okay, I'm out of ideas, and also using version 7.  I hope someone is able to help you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for trying. Have you ever seen anything like this before?  I don't know what `Removed[$$Failure]` means. I guess that it replaced a part of my expression where Mathematica was trying a transformation when it hit the TimeConstraint. Rather than return the untransformed piece of the expression (like it should), it returned `Return[$$Failure]`.  But I just made up that story.

Comment: Well I know what `Removed` is; you'll get it when you reference a Symbol that has been removed with `Remove` (not the same as `Removed`).  For example: `a = b; Remove[b]; a` returns `Removed["b"]`.  Unfortunately I don't recall seeing `$$Failure` and I don't know why you're getting it.

Comment: Hum, wild guess: maybe if you `Remove` and try to access a symbol in the same expression things fail? Then a symbol may have no `Context`, which could be a problem. Can somebody maybe try `{Remove[a],a}`? I have no MMA atm. I guess it makes sense to ask if you are using `Remove` anywhere in your code :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Running `{Remove[a],a}` returns simply `{Null, Removed[a]}`. There's no $$Failure anywhere. And I don't use `Remove` in my code.

Comment: jkrich, ok that didn't help. Hm I would be interested to see more of your code. Maybe you could use `Hold` and `Compress` to post it in more compact form? People here tend not to like a lot of lines of code, but if it is necessary to understand the problem I am sure they will understand.

Comment: Thanks for adding the expression.  I can now confirm the behavior exists also in version 7 on Windows.

Comment: I'm marking this as a bug.  It hasn't been confirmed as one by a consensus or official word yet but since nobody can provide an explanation I'm going to make a presumption.  Also, the bugs tag will make this easier to track/remember.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It certainly seems to be a bug, since it exists in multiple versions of MMA and @JacobAkkerboom found such a simple example of the problem.  In the short term, this is causing me some problems. Do you know of any way to list and exclude particular built-in transformation rules in `Simplify`, as mentioned in my comment to Jacob Akkerboom's answer? Any other workaround you can think of? I'm interested in having `Simplify` use whatever rules it can and return a usable expression (perhaps no simpler than the original).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of anything that will help.  If you find other expressions that cause a problem and it is a specific pattern (e.g. is it always `Cosh`?) we may be able to shield it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's an excellent suggestion!  I don't know what you meant by shielding it, but I just tried `Simplify[ expression1 /. Cosh -> cosh, Sinh -> sinh] /. cosh -> Cosh /. sinh -> Sinh`, and it returned a result without any `$$Failure`.  It's only slightly simpler than the original expression (`LeafCount` down by 10%), but it seems to be formatted correctly, so I can continue using it!

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of thing I had in mind.  If this is a persistent problem you could write a wrapper for `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` that make such replacements automatically, and even include this in your `init.m` file.  I've got several bug fixes in mine as I recall.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's easy enough to do. I don't think I want to put this kind of shielding into my `init.m`, because someday I might want to actually simplify those functions; for this application, though, it seems to be working.  I'm curious what other bug fixes you have in your `init.m`. I know it doesn't really fit in this forum, but maybe it would interesting for people to share their `init.m`s. I'm sure I'd learn a lot. Thanks again for the help. Also @JacobAkkerboom.

Comment: I still use version 7 so they likely don't apply to you.  Nevertheless a question (make it Community Wiki) asking for bug-fixes people load on start-up might be productive.

Comment: Reported as a bug. Will be looked into.

Comment: Seems like it has been fixed in version 10!

Comment: If true, that's definitely reason for me to upgrade! I don't have access to 10 yet, though.

Answer (score 7):

Not really an answer:

I get the same strange behavior, on Mac OSX v 9.0.0. The simplest case I could find where this happens is (thanks to @halirutan)

```
Simplify[Cosh[1/200] + E^(9200/257)]
```

> Removed[$$Failure]/(2 E^(1/200))

Comment: Very peculiar... How did you track down this example?

Comment: @sebhofer Trial, error and patience I'm afraid :P. I just worked my way "down" from the simplest case the OP provides.

Comment: Great effort :)

Comment: That's an excellent example.  Is there any way to find out what transformation function `Simplify` is using when this error occurs? Relatedly, is there a way to get the full list of built-in `TransformationFunctions` for `Simplify`?  Then maybe it is possible to exclude the offending function?