# What bug fixes can be implemented in init.m?

Tags: functions, system, initialization

In comments on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30462/7240), Mr. Wizard suggested a community wiki to share the bug fixes/workarounds (or possibly other tricks) people load in their `init.m`. I think this could provide a nice resource.

Comment: I think this should probably be restricted to bug fixes and workarounds or it becomes too broad.

Comment: Should these be version-tagged?

Comment: @Yves I think they should, and so far it looks like everyone has already done that.

Comment: Tangentially related: [(56728)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56728/121)

Answer (score 26):

Fixes by *Mathematica* version.  Note that unfixed bugs may apply to earlier versions as well; e.g. [TableAlignments -> Left not working](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7843/121) also applies to version 7.

## Version 10.1

- Fix [syntax highlighting in `Trace`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67356/121):

  ```
  Unprotect[Trace];
  SyntaxInformation[Trace] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _., OptionsPattern[]}};
  Protect[Trace];
  ```
- Fix [Incompatibility of Row and TeXForm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55363/121): (v9+)

  ```
  BoxForm`$UseTemplateSlotSequenceForRow = False;
  ```
- Fix [SetOptions for CoordinatesToolOptions for DateListPlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80038/121):

  ```
  DateListPlot;  (* preload; do not remove! *)

  With[
    {dv := DownValues[Graphics`DateListPlotDump`iDateListPlot]},
    dv = dv /.
      (fr : FilterRules)[a : Graphics`DateListPlotDump`opts, b_Options] :> 
        fr[Join[a, Options @ Graphics`DateListPlotDump`caller], b]
  ];
  ```
- Fix [TableAlignments -> Left not working](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7843/121)

  - code too long to include; provided in answer linked above
- Fix [In 10.1.0 BenchmarkPlot doesn't work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83226/121)

  - see answer to link above
- Fix [Strange Error on Fresh Kernel (10.2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91567/121):

  ```
  With[
    {dv := DownValues @ PacletManager`Package`loadWolframLanguageCode},
    dv = dv /. wl : HoldPattern[ToString @ $SystemWordLength] :> RuleCondition[wl];
  ]
  ```
- Fix [Problems with Displaying Output for Summation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110452/121)

  ```
  InactiveDump`assembleInactiveSumProduct[
     {args_, disp_, interp_, char_, tag_, tooltip_, fmt_}] := 
    TemplateBox[ args, tag,
      DisplayFunction -> Function[disp], 
      InterpretationFunction -> Function[interp],
      SyntaxForm -> char
    ]
  ```
- Fix [Inset in ArrayPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103192/121)

  ```
  Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`stripOptions[opt2___, OP_] := 
    Module[{opt = Flatten @ {opt2}}, 
     Delete[opt, 
      Position[opt, 
       g_?(System`Utilities`StringName[#1] === 
            System`Utilities`StringName[OP] &) -> _,
       {1}
      ]
     ]
    ];
  ```
- Fix [Conversion to TeX results in infinite recursion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76801/121)

  ```
  Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX; (* preload; do not remove! *)

  Begin["System`Convert`"]

  With[{DV := DownValues[`TeXFormDump`maketex], RLS := `CommonDump`RemoveLinearSyntax},
    DV = DV /.
       Verbatim[RLS][arg_, `CommonDump`Recursive -> val_] :>
        RLS[arg, `CommonDump`ConvertRecursive -> val]
  ]

  End[]
  ```

## Version 10.0

- Fix  [HoldForm doesn't hold form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55506/121):

  (fixed in 10.0.1)

  ```
  Visualization`Utilities`OptionsDump`unitFormStringQ[HoldForm[s_]] = False
  ```
- Fix  [BitShiftRight produces incorrect results in Version 10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56241/121):

  (fixed in 10.0.2)

  ```
  SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> {"MachineFunctionParallelThreshold2" -> Infinity}]
  ```
- Fix [A bug in Commonest in version 10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58760/121) (see link for an additional performance enhancement):

  (fixed in 10.0.2)

  ```
  Statistics`DescriptiveDump`oCommonestSetLength[list_, 1] := Commonest[list][[{1}]]
  ```
- Fix [10.0.2 mapping Association to Dataset warning](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68875/121):

  (fixed in 10.1.0)

  ```
  Begin["TypeSystem`Inference`PackagePrivate`"];

  exprType[e_Association] := 
   If[AssociationQ@Unevaluated@e, Struct@MapUn[exprType, e], TypeSystem`UnknownType];

  End[];
  ```

---

## Version 7

As a version 7 user these likely don't apply to most users but here are mine:

- Fix [Symbol name slow-down weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5402214/618728) (hashing problem?):

  ```
  SetSystemOptions["NeedNotReevaluateOptions"->{"UseSymbolLists"->True}];
  ```
- Fix [a bug](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Jun/msg00088.html) in `FullSimplify`:

  ```
  Unprotect[Holonomic`HolonomicFullSimplify];Clear[Holonomic`HolonomicFullSimplify];
  ```
- Prevent *Mathematica* from eating all my RAM and freezing (most of the time):

  ```
  $Pre = Function[Null, MemoryConstrained[Unevaluated @ #, 2^32, "Memory Exceeded"], HoldAll]
  ```

Comment: It would probably be good to include a version check before applying any fixes.

Comment: @Szabolcs Would you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: `If[$VersionNumber == (* number *), ( * do this *)]` was probably meant…

Comment: @J.M. Perhaps so.  I prefer to maintain the fixes manually.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, that's what I meant. It's critical when one has multiple versions installed. Doing this without a version check is dangerous. Someone might copy a fix from here, forget about it, update Mathematica, then something suddenly gets broken.

Answer (score 11):

Here is one that came from a Wolfram employee so it should be safe to add in version 9:

[FindInstance returns Indeterminate in version 9, but not in 8](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20860/245)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a patch from Adam Strzebonski of Wolfram, which fixes a bug in `RootReduce[]` in 9.0.1.

[ToNumberField won't recognize Root as explicit algebraic number](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23908/tonumberfield-wont-recognize-root-as-explicit-algebraic-number)