# HoldForm doesn't hold form

Tags: plotting, evaluation, bugs, formatting

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

In *Mathematica* version 10, `HoldForm` no longer produces the same results as in version 8 (**edit:** I only have versions 10 and 8 installed, so can't compare to version 9 directly). Here are some examples (on Mac OS X):

**Formatting of `\[ScriptCapitalE]`**

This symbol is output correctly:

```
InputForm[ℰ]
```

> `ℰ`

But when wrapped as follows, I get gibberish:

```
HoldForm[InputForm[ℰ]]
```

> `â °`

**Arguments in `HoldForm`aren't held**

Why would I want to use `InputForm` inside `HoldForm` in the first place? Here is one example, using the constant `E`. I would like it to be displayed as `E`:

```
HoldForm[InputForm[E]]
```

> `E`

On the other hand, the constant is formatted differently if I leave out `InputForm`:

```
HoldForm[E]
```

> 

So why not use `InputForm` without `HoldForm`? Because then I can't write assignments like this:

```
HoldForm[InputForm[E = 1]]
```

> `E = 1`

Here, I get no error because of `HoldForm`. So far, so good. But now things become inconsistent again if I put the same construct into a `Plot`:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, HoldForm[InputForm[E = 1]]}]
```

[image: plot error]

This used to work in version 8, but now it throws an error. The resulting plot is still correct, but the messages seem to indicate that `HoldForm` was ignored at some stage.

Indeed, I then proceeded to do a more basic test:

```
Clear[x];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", HoldForm[x = 3]}];
x
```

> `3`

Yes, that's right. `HoldForm` was completely ignored.

What can be done to fix this?

**Edit**

I tried to report the issue, but am currently receiving web form errors at the Wolfram site, so will have to try again later.

Comment: I suggest you report this to WRI tech support. Maybe WRI broke `HoldForm` when they added the new  `Inactivate`.

Comment: @m_goldberg Will do. There are no change notes for `HoldForm` in the docs, so I would think this is a regression.

Comment: Yes, and it's a nasty one. There is probably a lot of existing code broken by this behavior. And it's worse than even you think. Try substituting `Hold[x = 3]` for `HoldForm[x = 3]`. Global x still set to 3 after evaluation.

Comment: I agree that you should consider contacting support.  I'm not convinced that this is not by design, however.  I've always found `ThisForm[ThatForm[expr]]` to be a bit awkward.

Comment: Mark I also see your first example failing in V9 as well as V10.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I've updated my answer to address the first example as well.

Comment: Mark I meant that the `HoldForm[InputForm[ℰ]]` renders the same gibberrish for me in V9 as V10

Comment: In V10 on Windows 8.1 `HoldForm[InputForm[ℰ]]` works as expected. I don't get the gibberish.

Comment: In v10 under Windows I do not have the `HoldForm[InputForm[ℰ]]` problem but I do have the problems with `HoldForm` and `Plot`.  I'm tagging this a bug.

Comment: Off-topic: I usually prefer the `\[LongEqual]` symbol for (IMO) nicer appearance.

Comment: I just noticed that I never had the `InputForm` problem so I don't know if that has been fixed in 10.0.1 or not.  If that still exists please edit the header accordingly.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'll look at it when I get a chance to upgrade. I'm currently happily using a computer with only version 8 installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regarding the plot issue, I tried using `HoldForm[x = Stack[_]]` as an axis label to capture the stack at the moment of evaluation inside `HoldForm`. This revealed a problem in a helper function for dealing with units. The function `` Visualization`Utilities`OptionsDump`unitFormStringQ `` is applied to the axis labels (in a pattern test). The definition is this:

```
unitFormStringQ[s_] := Or @@ (MatchQ[#1, $unitFormString]&) /@ {Sequence @@ s}
```

The problem is clearly coming from `{Sequence @@ s}` which removes the `HoldForm` head.

A simple workaround is thus to define:

```
Visualization`Utilities`OptionsDump`unitFormStringQ[HoldForm[s_]] = False
```

Comment: Great analysis and solution for the main issue  -  it also works for `FrameLabel` where the same issue appeared.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure what's going on with `HoldForm[InputForm[ℰ]]`, but I think I know what's going on with `Plot`.

It appears at some point `ReleaseHold` is called because wrapping `HoldForm` twice fixes your problem.

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, HoldForm[HoldForm[InputForm[E = 1]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's a valuable observation, thanks!

Comment: What you observed also holds for `Hold` in the same context, so you must have hit the nail on the head. I  think this cannot have been done intentionally - it makes no sense.

Answer (score 8):

I can't comment on exactly why `HoldForm` has changed but I believe your examples fall under the purview of the new `Active`/`Inactive` functionality.  For example:

```
Clear[x];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {Inactivate[x = 3],
  Inactive[Set][InputForm[E], 3]}]
x
```

[image]

Note, however that `Inactivate` can't be used with `InputForm`, since you *want* `InputForm` to be applied.

The `[ScriptCapitalE] business has everything to do with your default character encoding.  Here are some results on my Mac:

[image]

I get the same results in both V9 and V10.  If your results are different, you might check the contents of `$CharacterEncoding`.  A list of all possible encodings is contained in `$CharacterEncodings`.

Comment: comparing the difference in ??Plot between V9 and V10, I noticed only difference is `PlotTheme:>` was added to V10. I do not know if this has anything to do with this change of behavior or not. This change might break existing code which used `HoldForm` in labels.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely a workaround in some cases. But unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue with my first `Plot` example, where I used the (admittedly contrived) label `HoldForm[InputForm[E = 1]]` to get `E` instead of the double-struck letter.

Comment: @Jens Does the edit help? I guess that you've got to selectively apply `Inactive` to `Set` but *not* to `InputForm`. So `Inactivate` is a bit too coarse.

Comment: I suspected that one could find a working character encoding, but of course I would like to keep the default encoding. Anyway, thanks for that find, too! In terms of using `Inactive[Set]`, I would then probably not bother and rewrite everything with `FormBox`es. But the fact that `Hold` has the same issue as `HoldForm` in `AxesLabel` **really** worries me.

Answer (score 1):

Considering work-arounds, `Style` and `Inactivate` seem to work well together.

```
Plot[x , {x, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> 
   {Style["M", Italic], 
    Style[Inactivate[InputForm[E] = M c^2, (Set | Times)], "TraditionalForm"]}]
```

[image: plot]

Inactivating `Times` keeps `M c^2` from being rewritten to `c^2 M`.