# BitShiftRight produces incorrect results in Version 10

Tags: bugs, numerics, binary

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

With Mathematica 10 for Mac, `BitShiftRight` works properly on lists of up to 100000 numbers, but appears to give incorrect results when threaded over lists of 100001 or more:

```
v1 = Table[i, {i, 1, 100000}];
v2 = Table[i, {i, 1, 100001}];
s1 = BitShiftRight[v1];
s2 = BitShiftRight[v2];
s1[[1 ;; 10]]
s2[[1 ;; 10]]
```

> ```
> Out[1070]= {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5}
>
> Out[1071]= {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}
> ```

The error seems to occur for any `BitShiftRight[n,k]` whenever n is a list exceeding 100000 values.

Mathematica 9 gives correct output:

```
v1 = Table[i, {i, 1, 100000}];
v2 = Table[i, {i, 1, 100001}];
s1 = BitShiftRight[v1];
s2 = BitShiftRight[v2];
s1[[1 ;; 10]]
s2[[1 ;; 10]]
```

> ```
> Out[799]= {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5}
>
> Out[800]= {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5}
> ```

I have several notebooks that apply `BitShiftRight[n,k]` to very large lists. The only Mathematica 10 workaround seems to be the equivalent `IntegerPart[n/2^k]` that continues to work on very large lists, but is slower and requires rewriting previously working code. Otherwise I would need to stick with MM 9 for these notebooks.

Can anyone confirm this anomalous MM 10 output? Does it affect other platforms? Am I missing something simple, or is this a true MM 10 bug?

Thanks

Comment: I can confirm the result on M10 running on Win7-64 (Ultimate).

Comment: That's a surprising bug.  Compact example: v = `Range[100001];
a = BitShiftRight[v[[;; 10]]];
b = BitShiftRight[v][[;; 10]];
a == b` is `False`.

Comment: I can confirm this on Windows 8.1. Interesting bug. `BitShiftLeft` works fine by the way.

Comment: I confirm that Mr. Wizard's Solution works on my system - but it is annoying to have to add this line to previously working code.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you.  I have added it to my kernel `init.m` file so that I don't have to worry about it again.  See: [(30599)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30599)

Comment: Thanks yet again - I've added it to init.m also. MachineFunctionParallelThreshold 1,2 and 3 appear to be new system parallel options in MM 10.

Comment: part 1: Here's a guess/suspicion I venture to suggest as a comment, which could be the cause. Try: max = $MaxNumber. After trying to contemplate that magnitude for a moment: max = Log[2, max] is Log[2, max]. So to me it looks as if WRI may have implemented a precision scheme, using the IEEE 64 bit floating point algorithm recursively by using the parallel framework.IEEE 64 bit gets 53 bit precision by always using the same first bit.

Comment: part 2: If you were to use it recursively, parallel or not, you would only get 52 bits on each precision level. The two things could be related if M is using integers in the same schema as rationals with no modular remainder; it wouldn't be hard to screw up the bit arithmetic if everything was being stored in an array of IEEE 64 bit floating point numbers using Intel's vector system. When you apply Developer`PackedArrayQ[v2] to the example you get True.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Solution

It appears this bug is the result of attempted parallelism gone wrong.
I believe it is corrected in all cases by setting this System Option:

```
SetSystemOptions[
 "ParallelOptions" -> {"MachineFunctionParallelThreshold2" -> Infinity}
]
```

This appears to be an out and out bug and I tagged the question accordingly.

---

### Original observations:

Compact example:

```
v = Range[100001];
a = BitShiftRight[v ~Take~ 10];
b = BitShiftRight[v] ~Take~ 10;
a == b
```

> ```
> False
> ```

This also affects (at least) tensors with more than 100,000 elements:

```
v = RandomInteger[99, {80, 80, 55}];
a = BitShiftRight[v ~Take~ 10];
b = BitShiftRight[v] ~Take~ 10;
a == b
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Fixed in 10.0.2

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
v1 = Table[i, {i, 1, 100000}];
v2 = Table[i, {i, 1, 100001}];
s1 = BitShiftRight[v1];
s2 = BitShiftRight[v2];
s1[[1 ;; 10]]
s2[[1 ;; 10]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
v = Range[100001];
a = BitShiftRight[v[[;; 10]]];
b = BitShiftRight[v][[;; 10]];
a == b
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]