# Reduce applied to vectors doesn't work right?

Tags: equation-solving

```
Reduce[{x,0}=={0,0}, x]
```

gives x==0 as it should, but

```
Reduce[{x,0}!={0,0}, x]
```

gives False, which indicates no solution and seems incorrect. What is going on?

Update: I reported the issue to Mathematica; they replied that they know about it and are working on a solution.

Update 2: The above bug is only present in Mathematica 10.0 and 10.1. Mathematica 9.x and 10.2 behave as expected.

Comment: Latter works fine for me on 9.x Win: `x!=0` result...

Comment: @ciao Interesting .... Seems that it doesn't on 10.x I got the same results in the question...

Comment: Something might have changed in the implementation of Equal or Reduce.

Comment: But I believe the 9.x behavior is the correct logical behavior. A list shouldn't be expanded like that.

Comment: Axel, that is interesting behavior indeed. Bichoy has an interesting explanation for what may be happening. I just wanted to suggest that `LogicalExpand` behaves in the way that you expected `Reduce` to behave, i.e. `LogicalExpand[{x, 0} != {0, 0}]` gives `x != 0`.

Comment: V8 and V9 both give x!=0. V10.0.2 and V10.1 both give False. Seems like a change introduced in V10 then.

Comment: While there certainly has been a change in the behavior of `Reduce`, I believe the new behavior is consistent with the way equations are treated in other solvers (i.e., threaded). I agree with @Sjoerd's comment under Bichoy's answer that this should not be considered a bug.

Comment: I'll remove the bugs tag, because it has not been vetted by the community as a bug (as the tag wiki says). See also michaelE2's answer.

Answer (score 10):

From Mathematica [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html):

> Reduce[{exp1,expr2,...},vars] is equivalent to Reduce[expr1 && expr2 && ..., var]

Thus, one explanation is that `Reduce[{x,0}!={0,0}, x]` is being expanded as if `{x,0}!={0,0}` is the same as `{x !=0, 0 != 0}`**. Hence, the second expression in `Reduce` returns `False` because `0 != 0` reduces to `False`.

To work around that, another level of listing might be applied:

```
Reduce[{{x,0}}!= {{0,0}}, x]
```

which yields `x != 0` as expected.

---

**I did check the documentation for `Equal` (`==`), and I couldn't find such behavior documented (I was expecting to find that `Equal` is `Listable` for example, but this is not shown by `Attributes[Equal]`). This behavior might be specific only to `Reduce`.

Comment: The double list trick is very useful, thanks! The explanation seems plausible; it's curious though that Reduce[{1,0}!={0,0}] gives True!

Comment: Reduce[{x,0}!={0,1},x] and Reduce[{x,0,0}!={0,0,1},x] also correctly give True!

Comment: @AxelBoldt, you are welcome.  There is definitely something wrong with Mathematica here. I think you should report to Wolfram as a bug, or ask for their explanation. Also the fact that this behavior was not in 9.x (check ciao comment on the question, makes it feel more like a bug.

Comment: @AxelBoldt That is not curious as {1, 0} != {0, 0} itself already reduces to true. So you end up with Reduce[True] which is True as well.

Comment: Proof of the expansion assumption: `Reduce[{x, y} != {0, 0}]` yields  `y != 0 && x != 0`. Next, fill in y->0.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a bug, though it's inconsistent behavior over the versions for sure. Nowhere in the documentation is it stated that equations of vectors are possible and should be interpreted in vector terms. I agree that the expansion interpretation isn't documented either. I believe that the current change in behavior may be caused by the addition of the possibility to use geometric region constraints, where we now can say {x,y} $\in$ Circle which may have caused elements like {x,y} to be parsed differently than before.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries You are right and I think that what you are describing is exactly the problem. The correct logical expansion for `Reduce[{x,y}!={0,0}]` should be `x != 0 || y != 0`  not `&&` (De Morgan's law) if we assume that `{x,y}` and `{0,0}` should be treated as vectors, i.e., a single entity.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I think another possible reason for the change is that after version 8 equations between lists were allowed in `DSolve`, and there they must be interpreted by threading `Equal` over lists - that's what is automatically done here, too.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries by referring to a bug, I meant the discrepancy in the discrepancy in the behavior between `Reduce[{x,0,0}!={0,0,1},x]` and `Reduce[{x, 0} != {0, 0}]`, which both doesn't seem right to me. This is different behavior for the same rule in the same version (10.x).

Comment: @Jens Maybe  a good reason, but clearly `!=` is causing a problem here ... De Morgan's law get dropped somewhere :)

Comment: @Bichoy Yes, I'm just making up a guess here - maybe totally unrelated... for `Equal`, the same could happening as with `UnEqual`, only we don't see the difference...

Comment: @Bichoy The comment I made to Axel above also holds for `{x,0,0}!={0,0,1}`. This, on it's own, already reduces automatically (and correctly so) to False.

Comment: @jens True. I recall that I used to do Solve[Thread[xvec==yvec]], but I forgot when the change occurred, so I didn't dare to pint to this as a possible cause.

Comment: @Sjoerd The [tutorial on Simultaneous Equations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SimultaneousEquations.html) has an example that uses == between lists, interpreted as equation of vectors.

Comment: @axel I believe you're interpreting this incorrectly. It says it's a way to describe simultaneous equations (it's even using lhs and rhs in the naming of things). So it certainly does not refer to vector equations.

Answer (score 8):

A long comment on [@Bichoy's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6770/bichoy) answer, which seems quite correct:  `Reduce` first applies `Thread` on the "vector" (in)equality and the lists are combined with `And` as pointed out.

```
Trace[
 Reduce[{x, 0} == {0, 0}, x],
 TraceInternal -> True]
(*
  {Reduce[{x, 0} == {0, 0}, x], {$MessageList = {}, {}},
   {Thread[{x, 0} == {0, 0}], {x == 0, 0 == 0}, {0 == 0, True}, {x == 0, True}},
   {$MessageList, {}},
   {x == 0 && True, And[x == 0], x == 0}, ..., x == 0}
*)

Trace[
 Reduce[{x, 0} != {0, 0}, x],
 TraceInternal -> True]
(*
  {Reduce[{x, 0} != {0, 0}, x], {$MessageList = {}, {}},
   {Thread[{x, 0} != {0, 0}], {x != 0, 0 != 0},
   {0 != 0, False}, {x != 0, False}}, {$MessageList, {}},
   {x != 0 && False, False}, ..., False}
*)
```

But `Reduce` applies `Thread` only once. On Bichoy's insightful workaround, it then compares the elements of the lists with `Or`:

```
Trace[
 Reduce[{{x, 0}} != {{0, 0}}, x],
 TraceInternal -> True]
(*
  {Reduce[{{x, 0}} == {{0, 0}}, x], {$MessageList = {}, {}},
   {Thread[{{x, 0}} != {{0, 0}}], {{x, 0} != {0, 0}}}, ...,
   {x != 0 || 0 != 0, {0 != 0, False}, Or[x != 0], x != 0}, ...}
*)
```

Executing the same commands on V9 shows that `Reduce` does not apply `Thread`, but compares lists using `And` for `Equal` and `Or` for `Unequal` (similar to the preceding example).

It seems like a change that will break things, but it's not mentioned on the [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) documentation page.  Perhaps the change should be added to [Incompatible Changes since Mathematica Version 7?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56728/incompatible-changes-since-mathematica-version-7) or [Will Version 9 functions all work in Version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54481/will-version-9-functions-all-work-in-version-10)

Comment: very nice! I got the intuition about what was going on, but could never verify it. 
BTW, how do I find more about the options of Trace? TraceInternal -> True doesn't seem to be in `Trace` documentation. (Should we start a new question about `Trace` and expand on the details of that?)

Comment: @Bichoy See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67305/where-is-the-old-option-traceinternal-true