# Transform a vector DE into a set of scalar DEs

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, vector

I have the vector equality:

```
{{a,b},{c,d}}.D[{x1[t],x2[t]},t]=={{e,f},{g,h}}.{u1[t],u2[t]}
```

I want to solve this using `DSolve`. How do I transform the above *vector* equality into a list of 2 scalar equalities (automatically):

```
{a*x1'[t]+b*x2'[t]==e*u1[t]+f*u2[t], c*x1'[t]+d*x2'[t]==g*u1[t]+h*u2[t]}
```

How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: `Thread[]` ought to work.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Awesome, `Thread[LHS==RHS]` (pseudocode) worked!

Comment: In recent versions of *Mathematica*, you do *not* have to transform the vector equation into a pair of scalar equations before using solving them. Thus `DSolve[{{a, b}, {c, d}}.D[{x1[t], x2[t]}, 
    t] == {{e, f}, {g, h}}.{u1[t], u2[t]}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t]` works just fine as is, whether with "abstract" functions `u[t], u2[t]` and symbolic coefficient matrices, or with specific functions and actual values in the coefficient matrices.

Comment: Though we had a question that showed that this 'improvement ' leads to problems.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries can you provide a link please?

Comment: @chris It was rather difficult to find, but I believe I was alluding to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84824/reduce-applied-to-vectors-doesnt-work-right).