# Add column heads to a dataset

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset which I group an then calculate the maximum of an item. When done I get the desired result, but have no column heads. 
Here the example association (subset of my data):

```
tn = {<|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "01", "different" -> 15028|>, <|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "02", "different" -> 15105|>, <|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "03", "different" -> 15976|>, <|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "04",  "different" -> 14016|>, <|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "05", "different" -> 14196|>, <|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "06", "different" -> 14068|>, <|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "07", "different" -> 15321|>, <|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "08", "different" -> 15034|>, <|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "09", "different" -> 14745|>, <|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "10", "different" -> 15160|>, <|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "11", "different" -> 15069|>, <|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "12", "different" -> 15982|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "01", "different" -> 14381|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "02", "different" -> 14721|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "03", "different" -> 15965|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "04", "different" -> 15546|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "05", "different" -> 15024|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "06", "different" -> 14225|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "07", "different" -> 14554|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "08", "different" -> 16700|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "09", "different" -> 14965|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "10", "different" -> 16788|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "11", "different" -> 15382|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "12", "different" -> 16606|>}
```

I form a dataset with

```
ds = Dataset @ tn
```

and make the calculation:

```
ds[GroupBy[#year &]][All, All, "different"][All, Max]
```

Everything is fine, but I have no heads over the columns (I would like to have "year" and "max") - I could not see how to achieve this. Any hints?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Working From The Original Expression**

The expression proposed in the question can be simplified slightly:

```
ds[GroupBy[#year&], Max, "different"]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This expression can be adjusted to generate a separate association for each year:

```
ds[GroupBy[#year&] /* Normal, Max, "different"][All, <|"year"->First, "max"->Last|>]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

**Using `GroupBy` With Reduction**

Alternatively, we could add a reduction function to the `GroupBy` expression:

```
ds[GroupBy[#, #year &, MaximalBy[#different &] /* First] &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

From this we can extract the desired output:

```
ds[ GroupBy[#, #year&, MaximalBy[#different&] /* First] &
 ][ Values, <|"year"->"year", "max"->"different"|>
 ]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. The second way is similar to my workaround, but by far more clear.

Answer (score 7):

```
ds[GroupBy[#year &], MaximalBy[#different &]][
  Catenate][All, <|"year" -> #year, "max" -> #different|> & ]
```

> ```
> {<|"year" -> "2004", "max" -> 15982|>, <|"year" -> "2005", 
>   "max" -> 16788|>}
> ```

Or, if you don't mind "month" key in the output:

```
ds[GroupBy[#year &], MaximalBy[#different &]][Catenate][
  All, <|#, "max" -> #different|> & ]
```

> ```
> {<|"year" -> "2004", "month" -> "12", "different" -> 15982, 
>   "max" -> 15982|>, <|"year" -> "2005", "month" -> "10", 
>   "different" -> 16788, "max" -> 16788|>}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way... I simply have overseen the function MaximalBy which is very convenient here...

Comment: Another Question: What Version of Mathematica do you use. I´m on 10.0.2.0 and the last part of your first suggestion does not work ([All, <|"year" -> #year, "max" -> #different|> & ]). I get a different output. (???)

Comment: @mgamer Unfortunately 10.0.2.0 introduced some regressions that interfere with the operation of this code.  One of the WRI developers acknowledged the bug and provided a patch [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/68879/142).

Comment: @Wreach: Thank you for the link. I gave it a try, but it seems that it has other side effects (a faced errors in other notebooks which make heavy use of dataset). I made a workaround for me... now waiting for 10.0.3 ;-)