# SetOptions for CoordinatesToolOptions for DateListPlot?

Tags: plotting, bugs, options, date-and-time

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.0 or later**

---

[`DateListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html) does not respect my [`Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html) setting for [`CoordinatesToolOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinatesToolOptions.html):

```
SetOptions[
  DateListPlot, 
  CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> MapAt[DateString, 1]}
];

DateListPlot[{{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {5, 8, 9, 6, 2, 4, 7}}, {2013, 1, 1}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

However if this option is given explicitly it works as desired:

```
DateListPlot[{{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {5, 8, 9, 6, 2, 4, 7}}, {2013, 1, 1}, 
 Joined -> True, CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> MapAt[DateString, 1]}]
```

[image]

**1. Why is my global Option value ignored?**

**2. What is the cleanest way to make `DateListPlot` respect my setting?**

(Observations in 10.0.2 under Windows.)

Comment: I am too tired to work through this right now so I would like to let the community solve it for me while I sleep. :^)

Comment: `MapAt[DateString, 1]` throws error called with 2 arguments, 3 arguments expected. or do I miss something ?  PS; I didn't know that wizards sleep ???

Comment: @penguin77 It is a version 10+ [operator form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56504/121)

Comment: I observe the same behavior in V10.1 (Mac OSX).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I would like to tag this as a bug.  Please review my analysis and tell me if you think that is reasonable.

Comment: I already had looked at it and tried to figure it out.  I gave up before I got very far. I would agree that it is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option value is ignored because `DateListPlot` calls `` Graphics`DateListPlotDump`iDateListPlot `` which only uses `Options` for these items:

```
{PlotRange, AxesOrigin, GridLines, GridLinesStyle, Epilog, Prolog, Frame, Axes, Ticks,
FrameTicks, DateTicksFormat, DateFunction, DataRange, PlotRangePadding, PlotLegends,
PlotStyle, PlotMarkers, Joined, BaseStyle, LabelStyle, TargetUnits, Method}
```

The values of these options are modified as needed, then combined with explicit options after the latter are filtered with:

```
opts = FilterRules[opts, Options[If[caller === DateListLogPlot, ListLogPlot, ListPlot]]];
```

Therefore we can patch the broken definition with this replacement:

```
DateListPlot; (* preload; do not remove! *)

With[
  {dv := DownValues[Graphics`DateListPlotDump`iDateListPlot]},
  dv = dv /.
    (fr : FilterRules)[a : Graphics`DateListPlotDump`opts, b_Options] :> 
      fr[Join[a, Options @ Graphics`DateListPlotDump`caller], b]
];
```

Now:

```
SetOptions[DateListPlot, 
  CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> MapAt[DateString, 1]}];

DateListPlot[{{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {5, 8, 9, 6, 2, 4, 7}}, {2013, 1, 1}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Nice spelunking.  Note that the `DateListPlot` stuff has to be loaded before you fix the options.  (I did it on a new kernel and it had no effect the first time.)  Simply prepending `DateListPlot;` before `With` is sufficient, as you would probably know.

Comment: @Michael Thanks.  For some reason it seemed like preloading was not needed here but now that I try it again it seems it is; I don't know what mistake I made, but this is a good lesson to use preloading as a matter of practice.  Correction imminent.

Comment: @Michael I'll bet I used `SetOptions[DateListPlot, . . .]` before the replacement patch in my testing; I cannot think of another explanation for the behavior I observed earlier.

Comment: `SetOptions[DateListPlot, ... ]` still does not work properly in 10.2 -- I tried `PlotLegends -> Automatic` and it is not working.

Comment: @gwr Thanks for the notice.  I'll update the banner to include 10.2 specifically.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you might also remove the `CoordinatesToolOptions` constraint in the title? The issue seems to be broader if something like `PlotLegends` does not work in `SetOptions`, doesn't it?

Comment: @gwr Hang on, unless the problem has gotten worse `PlotLegends` should work as it is one of the options that is explicitly checked.  (See the list in my answer above.)  If that is not working it might be a separate problem?  Please give me an example and I shall see how it behaves in 10.1.0.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Use `SetOptions[ DateListPlot, PlotLegends -> Automatic]` then simply plot two TimeSeries by `DateListPlot[TimeSeries @@@ {{{1, 2, 3}, {1}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {1}}}]`. Result: No legends, but if you add the options directly they will be plotted.

Comment: @gwr I got around to looking at that example, and I agree it seems buggy, but it originates for a different reason.  It seems that the PlotTheme supersedes the `Options` for `DateListPlot` and the it uses `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"`.  That option does not appear to be valid for `DateListPlot`.  If after using `SetOptions` you evaluate `DateListPlot[TimeSeries @@@ {{{1, 2, 3}, {1}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {1}}}, PlotTheme -> None]` you will see that the legend option is respected.

Comment: @gwr I posted [(89093)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89093/121) regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider this:

```
DateListPlot[{{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {5, 8, 9, 6, 2, 4, 7}}, {2013,1,1}, Joined -> True, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> (DateString@First@# &)}]
```

Then let's try this:

```
SetOptions[DateListPlot, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> (DateString@First@# &)}];
 DateListPlot[{{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {5, 8, 9, 6, 2, 4, 7}}, {2013, 
 1, 1}, Joined -> True]
```

Works perfectly well using M9. Sorry cannot test under M10.0.2.

Not sure what went wrong in your example. May be the expression following `"DisplayFunction"->` was not enclosed in parenthesis `()`, or there might be an incompatible issue with M10?

Coordinates showing date string and value:

```
SetOptions[DateListPlot, 
  CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> 
       (Row[{DateString@First@#, " -> ", Last@#}] &)}];

DateListPlot[{{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {5, 8, 9, 6, 2, 4, 7}}, {2013,1, 1}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Can anybody please try the code above to see if it works under M10.0.2 ? Before Mr Wizard wakes up, please, psssst :)

Comment: Oops, too late! ;-)

Comment: This does not work in 10.0.2 so I must assume it is a bug.  I'll wait for confirmation from other before tagging it as such.  Hopefully it is fixed in 10.1.0.

Comment: Anyway, [His uniqueness isn't  a proven fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_in_popular_culture)

Comment: @belisarius http://i.imgur.com/BbF29HJ.gif :-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, if not fixed in 10.1.0 we can swap our Mma licenses.........it's called the penguin's trick,.....undocumented.... :)