# PlotLegends "Expressions" default for ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, legending, language-design, plot-themes

[gwr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/764/gwr) pointed out [an apparent problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80038/setoptions-for-coordinatestooloptions-for-datelistplot#comment242946_80499) with setting a default Option value of [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) for [`DateListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html).  I traced the problem to the existence of `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"` in the default [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html).  This is true for [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) as well.  Since the explicit options within the Plot Theme override options set with [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html) it *appears* that our option is ignored.

Actually `"Expressions"` is used across many Themes for `ListPlot`:

```
PlotLegends /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Default", ListPlot] & /@
  {"Default", "Web", "Classic", "Detailed", "Scientific"}
```

> ```
> {"Expressions", "Expressions", "Expressions", "Expressions", "Expressions"}
> ```

Why would this be?  This option value doesn't seem to even work with these plot types, i.e.

```
dat = Table[{k, PDF[BinomialDistribution[50, p], k]}, {p, {0.3, 0.5, 0.8}}, {k, 0, 50}];

ListPlot[dat, Filling -> Axis, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

However it *does* cause the Themes to ignore a manually set default `PlotLegends` value:

```
SetOptions[ListPlot, PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, {"one", "two", "three"}]];

ListPlot[dat, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Observe that turning off the Plot Theme causes the legend to suddenly appear:

```
 ListPlot[dat, Filling -> Axis, PlotTheme -> None]
```

[image]

Unless `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"` has some *desirable* effect I have failed to observe this seems like plainly *undesirable* behavior.  Was the inclusion of `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"` in the Themes for `ListPlot` and related functions a mistake?

(All observations made in *Mathematica* 10.1.0 under Windows.)

Comment: I reported it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @rcollyer You're welcome and thank you too.

Comment: @MinHsuanPeng Would you care to post that as an answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Okay, I will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Expressions" for legend in ListPlot family is used because of Association. With Association input, the plot will automatically pick up the keys as legends. Here is an example:

`ListPlot[<|"A"->{1,2,3},"B"->{2,3,4}|>]`

[image]

SetOptions is to set the default values to options but it doesn't guarantee that the settings will be used by the plot since PlotTheme has been introduced.

The workaround would be to pack a set of options you would like to use through out the session in a variable and use it instead of using SetOptions.

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be with specifying `Automatic` for the colors with `PointLegend` rather than letting it default.

```
$Version
```

> "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"

```
pValues = {0.3, 0.5, 0.8};

dat = Table[{k, PDF[BinomialDistribution[50, p], k]}, {p, pValues}, {k, 0, 50}];

ListPlot[dat, Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[("p = " <> ToString[#] & /@ pValues)]]
```

[image]

Or just use

```
ListPlot[dat, Filling -> Axis, PlotLegends -> ("p = " <> ToString[#] & /@ pValues)]
```

Comment: Bob Hanlon, I am afraid I did not craft my question clearly enough.  The trouble is not manifest when the `PlotLegends` option is given *directly* to `ListPlot`, but rather when it is first set with `SetOptions` or `Options[ListPlot] = . . .`.  Direct specification works as it supersedes Theme options.  My question is really about Themes and why `"Expressions"` is used at all.