SetOptions does not work for ContourStyle of ContourPlot3D?
$Version
14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)

This seems to be similar to Global LabelStyle option does not work with SetOptions and SetOptions for CoordinatesToolOptions for DateListPlot?
Starting with a fresh kernel, the option ContourStyle->Opacity[0.1] works as expected,
m=2;

opt:=FilterRules[Options@ContourPlot3D,ContourStyle];

opt

ContourPlot3D[x==y,{x,-m,m},{y,-m,m},{t,-m,m},ContourStyle->Opacity[0.1]]


But SetOptions does not change the final plot.
SetOptions[ContourPlot3D,ContourStyle->Opacity[0.1]];

opt

ContourPlot3D[x==y,{x,-m,m},{y,-m,m},{t,-m,m}]



Is there any workaround for this and similar problems?
The definition of ContourPlot3D can be accessed by GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal, but the codes of passing options are quite complicated and I have no idea how to fix it.

It seems that PlotTheme has higher piority over other options like ContourStyle, and Charting`ResolvePlotTheme will generate a "default" option value of ContourStyle according to the theme, which will overwrite the the option value of ContourStyle from SetOptions.
Here is an ad hoc fixing, as in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80499/86893.
SetOptions[ContourPlot3D,ContourStyle->Opacity[0.1]];

(*load the code.*)
System`SampledPlotsDump`iContourPlot3D;

(*memorize the old definition.*)
old=DownValues[System`SampledPlotsDump`iContourPlot3D];

then we drop the option value of ContourStyle generated by Charting`ResolvePlotTheme:

DownValues[System`SampledPlotsDump`iContourPlot3D]=
    ReplaceAll[old,
        HoldPattern[FilterRules[arg_,Verbatim[Except][Method]]]:>
            FilterRules[arg,Except[Method|ContourStyle]]
    ];

and SetOptions works as expected:
m=2;

ContourPlot3D[x==y,{x,-m,m},{y,-m,m},{t,-m,m}]


the original definition can be restored by
DownValues[System`SampledPlotsDump`iContourPlot3D]=old;

for fixing other options.
