# Inset in ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

It seems the options in the `Inset` object will be ignored when passing to `ArrayPlot`:

```
ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[30, {{1}, 0}, 10],
Epilog -> Inset[Plot[Sin[x],{x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True]]]
```

Apparently, no frame is shown in the `Inset`:

[image]

However, once the insetting is done via `Show`, the option `Frame->True` turns out to be working again:

```
Show[ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[30, {{1}, 0}, 10]], 
Epilog -> Inset[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True]]]
```

(* output: *)

[image]

Can someone please explain the behavior of `Inset` in `ArrayPlot`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you compare the output expression of your two examples, you see that the `Graphics` object that is inset into the `ArrayPlot` is stripped off the `Frame` option. Knowing this, there are several ways to prevent this.

A very easy and not hacked solution is to evaluate the `ArrayPlot` and insert the `Epilog` in the final `Graphics`:

```
Append[
 ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[30, {{1}, 0}, 10]],
 Epilog -> Inset[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True]]
]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can we consider such behavior a bug of `ArrayPlot`?

Comment: Yes, I would consider this a bug and you should definitely write a report to support@wolfram.com

Answer (score 6):

This is interesting and peculiar.  Spelunking this example lead my discovery of the function:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`stripOptions // PrintDefinitions
```

> ```
> Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`stripOptions[opt2___, discard_List] := 
>   Module[{opt = 
>      Flatten[{opt2}]}, ((opt = 
>         Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`stripOptions[opt, #1]) &) /@ discard; opt];
>
> Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`stripOptions[opt2___, OP_] := 
>   Module[{opt = opt2}, 
>    Delete[opt, 
>     Position[opt, 
>      g_?(System`Utilities`StringName[#1] === 
>           System`Utilities`StringName[OP] &) -> _]]];
> ```

So there exists a function specifically for discarding unwanted options within an expression.

It is used by `ArrayPlot` expressly for `Frame`:

```
tr = Trace @ ArrayPlot[{Range@5}, Epilog -> Inset["foo"]];

Cases[tr, x : HoldPattern[Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`stripOptions[_, Frame]] :> 
  HoldForm[x], -1, 1]
```

> ```
> {Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`stripOptions[
>   Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`opt$7350, Frame]}
> ```

`` Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`opt$xxx `` contains our `Inset`:

> ```
> {Epilog -> Inset["foo"], GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]]}
> ```

I believe that `stripOptions` should not have been written to operate at all levels of the expression.  It could instead have been written to operate at only *levelspec* `{1}` if first the option list were flattened.

#### Here is a patch to effect this:

```
Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`stripOptions[opt2___, OP_] := 
  Module[{opt = Flatten @ {opt2}}, 
   Delete[opt, 
    Position[opt, 
     g_?(System`Utilities`StringName[#1] === 
          System`Utilities`StringName[OP] &) -> _,
     {1}
    ]
   ]
  ];
```

Now:

```
ArrayPlot[
 CellularAutomaton[30, {{1}, 0}, 10], 
 Epilog -> Inset[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True]]
]
```

[image]

Please let me know if you discover any failures induced by this patch.

Comment: +1, A simpler workaround is to exclude this `stripOptions` for the needed option ``Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`stripOptions[opt2___, Frame] := opt2``

Comment: @Algohi I presumed that there is a reason that `Frame` to be stripped in some cases and I wanted to modify the behavior as little as possible.  My *best guess* is that the function should have been written to operate only at level one, as described.  Thanks for the vote!

Answer (score 5):

This does seem to be a bug because it doesn't happen in other related functions, such as [`ReliefPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReliefPlot.html).

Here is a way to emulate the desired behavior with `ReliefPlot`:

```
ReliefPlot[CellularAutomaton[30, {{1}, 0}, 10], 
  LightingAngle -> None,
  ColorFunction -> Function[Blend[{White, Black}, #]], 
 DataReversed -> True, 
 Epilog -> Inset[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True]]]
```

[image: array sim]