# When a 2D plot is used as an Epilog to the MatrixPlot, the frame disappears. Any workarounds?

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs

So, I faced this problem, which is probably because of the bug.

Let's plot a simple 2D graph.

```
sample2dPlot = 
 ListPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100], Background -> White, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

Let's try to use it as the Epilog to the MatrixPlot

```
MatrixPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 100}], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> Inset[sample2dPlot]]
```

[image]

The frame disappeared, the frame labels disappeared.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Can confirm this as a bug, going back at least to version 8.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [(103192)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103192/31159). In particular, the patch given by Mr. Wizard in his [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129377/31159) can be applied here.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

Here's another workaround, based on the same underlying idea as the original:

```
MatrixPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 100}], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  Epilog -> "foo"] /. "foo" -> Inset[sample2dPlot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original answer:**

I guess this is a workaround:

```
MatrixPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 100}], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> Dynamic@Inset[sample2dPlot]]
```

(The underlying idea was to keep `MatrixPlot` from messing the options, assuming it does. In any case it works on the OP's example, if you have dynamic updating enabled.  I find the dependence on `Dynamic` less satisfactory for this reason.)