# Problems with Displaying Output for Summation

Tags: bugs, output-formatting, expression-manipulation, output

**Bug introduced in 10.2.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.4.0**

---

Consider the following code.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
InactSum = Inactive[Sum]
InactInt = Inactive[Integrate]
A = InactInt[
    Subscript[\[Phi], j][x] InactSum[
    Subscript[a, i] Subscript[\[Phi], i][x], {i, 1, n}] , {x, a, b}]
B = InactInt[
    InactSum[Subscript[a, i]
    Subscript[\[Phi], i][x] Subscript[\[Phi], j][x], {i, 1, n}] , {x,
    a, b}]
Interchange = InactInt[InactSum[p_, q_], r_] -> InactSum[InactInt[p, r], q];
A /. Interchange
B /. Interchange
```

I have introduced two expressions

$$\begin{align}
A &= \int_{a}^{b} \phi_{j}(x) \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \phi_{i}(x) \right] dx \\
B &= \int_{a}^{b} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \phi_{i}(x) \phi_{j}(x)\right] dx
\end{align}$$

where in $A$, $\phi_{j}$ is outside the summation while in $B$ it is inside the summation. Technically, these are both the same. But when I was trying to write a transformation rule that interchanges the integration and summation, then I noticed that it just applies to $B$ and **not** to $A$. So, I understood that Mathematica understands the **little** difference between these two but

**The Standard Output for Both is the Same!**

[image]

This prevents user from understanding the difference and it just shows itself when you want to apply the transformation rule.

I think this is a bug. In my opinion, the standard output for these two should be different. I would be happy to see what you think.

Comment: Version 10.4 Win 7 Pro 64bit does not display both the same ([see here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8WivM.png)). What version are you using?

Comment: @Edmund: Thanks for the attention. :) I am using Mathmatica 10.3 on Window 7 32bit. :) It is due to system settings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug I fixed in 10.4.0.  Sorry for the inconvenience!  To work around it in earlier versions, evaluate the following block of code:

```
InactiveDump`assembleInactiveSumProduct[{args_, disp_, interp_, char_,
    tag_, tooltip_, fmt_}] := 
  TemplateBox[args, tag, DisplayFunction -> Function[disp], 
    InterpretationFunction -> Function[interp], SyntaxForm -> char]
```

The `SyntaxForm` which specifies precedence for parenthesization was missing before 10.4.0.